# Relationships with relationships in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In Neo4j, is it possible for a relationship to have a relationship?

To illustrate: Imagine a domain model that encompasses a collection of geometric planes. Each plane has a collection of lines on it, and each line has a collection of points on it. Each point on a line is connected to the point after it by an outgoing `-[NEXT]->` relationship, and to the point preceding it by an incoming one. The way I have it now, each of these `NEXT` relationships contains a property `lineID`, which identifies the line on which it exists: The node entities representing lines in the database contain only an `id`, and perhaps a bit of metadata, and we return line X by traversing the graph, finding all `-[NEXT{lineID:X}]->` relationships, fetching the start and end nodes of each and returning an list of them along with the line's metadata.

I was a bit more longwinded there than I intended to be, but my question is this: What if, rather than having a `lineID` property on each `[NEXT]` relationship, I wanted to create an `-[ON]->` relationship between each `[NEXT]` and the node entity representing the line it is on?

To illustrate: Rather than doing

```
CREATE (:point)-[:NEXT{lineID:x}]->(:point)-[:NEXT{lineID:x}-> ...
```

, what about something like:

```
CREATE (:point)-[z:NEXT]->(:point), (z)-[:ON]->(:line)`
```

That's some ugly cypher, but I hope it clarifies my point. Intuitively, it seems like this would make line traversals more efficient (because we'd be playing to neo4j's strength by asking it to traverse all `[ON]` relationships from a line node rather than simply searching for a (presumably indexed) property. It would also make it easier to specify nested relationships:

```
(z)-[:ON]->(:line), (z)-[:ON]->(:plane)
```

Is this intuition misconceived? If not, would something like this be possible? I don't think it is, but am contemplating a workaround that would involve creating a node entity for each "relationship". Something like this:

```
(:point)<-[:FROM]-(x:next)-[:TO]->(:point), (x)-[:ON]->(:line)
```

, which would have the added advantage of facilitating [hypergraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) structures, which is something else I'm interested in. Leaving that conversation for another day (and another post), would such an approach be more trouble/expensive than its worth the purposes elucidated here? Might there be any dis/advantages (aside from plain cost) I'm not considering? Or am I reinventing the wheel here - is there an extant solution in this situation that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1):

There are no relationships that you can link to other relations. I think that when you ask yourself this kind of questions, you may have a modelling problem for your data, and the next thing to do is try to model the data differently. For instance, why the relationship that links two points knows the line on which the points are ? Wouldn't it be more natural that the point knows the line, therefore having the property `lineID` on the points? This way you may have points on several lines, which you can't model properly if the `lineID` is on the `NEXT` relationship. Perhaps even better, you can have a node `Line` that has a relationship `CONTAINS` with all the points on that particular line instead of using `lineID` property.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
Restructure your model so any data on your relationship which needs linking is a node